# Stuck at simplifying boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm getting stuck at the following boolean expression.

$$z + (x'y) + (xy') + (xt') + (yt')$$

In my solutions it's simplified and the $(yt')$ term is gone. How do they simplify this? I really cant see it....

Many thanks!

Comment: as i see it you're only allowing x and y to be different from the 2nd and 3rd terms, so only one of the 4th and 5th can be the case

Comment: I think i understand what you mean but is there a simple theorem or rule to simplify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from the [Consensus Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem). Notice that:
\begin{align*}
x'y + xt' + yt'
&= x'y + xt' + (1)yt' \\
&= x'y + xt' + (x + x')yt' \\
&= x'y + xt' + (xyt' + x'yt') \\
&= (x'y + x'yt') + (xt' + xyt') \\
&= x'y(1 + t') + xt'(1 + y) \\
&= x'y(1) + xt'(1) \\
&= x'y + xt' \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i needed!